# Vakil Exercise 6.6.T

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm having trouble with the following exercise from Professor Vakil's book.

> EXERCISE. As $A^1_\mathbb{Z}$ is a group scheme, $\mathbb{Z}[t]$ has a Hopf algebra structure.
>   Describe the comultiplication map $\mathbb{Z}[t] \to \mathbb{Z}[t]\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

My only guess was the map that sends $t$ to $t \otimes t$ (and the rest is determined by linearity). I want to describe the map $A^1_\mathbb{Z} \times A^1_\mathbb{Z} \to A^1_\mathbb{Z}$ which behaves like "multiplication" on points, so that was my guess. How do I check it though? I think the "addition of points" map would send $t$ to $t \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes t$, but I'm not sure about this one either.

EDIT: Can you please transfer this question to mathoverflow.net? Thank you

Comment: The latter is correct. Instead of using $t$ for both the lines, use $t,u$ so as to avoid confusion. Then the Hopf algebra map would be $\mathbb{Z}[t]\to \mathbb{Z}[u]\otimes\mathbb{Z}[v]=\mathbb{Z}[u,v]$, given by $t\mapsto u+v$.

Comment: @Mohan isn't that the coaddition map? What about the comultiplication map?

Comment: As a group scheme, affine line is a group scheme only with respect to addition, not multiplication.

Comment: @Mohan Isn't it a ring scheme? So I think there should be a comultiplication (it's a monoid I guess?).

Comment: @Mohan I guess the question is harder than I thought! Should I ask on mathoverflow.net?

Comment: I think that Mohan's right. And, this would be off-topic at MathOverflow. It is not at research level.

Answer (score 0):

Addition is the only group operation available on $\Bbb{A}^1$.
The way this translates into a comultiplication rule is the following. If $p(t)\in\Bbb{Z}[t]$, then $$\Delta p(t)=\sum_i p_{1,i}(t)\otimes p_{2,i}(t)$$ 
must be such a combination that for all integers $u,v$ we get
$$\sum_ip_{1,i}(u)p_{2,i}(v)=p(u+v).$$ So by the binomial formula
$$\Delta t^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom n i t^i\otimes t^{n-i}.$$
Extend that additively.

---

In other words $\Delta t=t\otimes1+1\otimes t$ works. The above sum is just
$(t\otimes 1+1\otimes t)^n$.